# Specifying SD card mount options upon boot

Tags: external-sd, mount, ext3

I have an Archos 101IT with a 16G external SD card. The SD card contains one partition that is formatted as an ext3 file system. The Archos runs UrukDroid 1.6.4 (Froyo 2.2).

The Problem: When booted, the SD card is mounted with the following mount options:

```
/dev/block/vold/179:17 on /mnt/storage/sdcard type ext3
(rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,fmode=0666,dmode=0666,errors=continue,data=ordered)
```

The fmode and dmode options make it impossible to use file permissions, in particular it is not possible to make files read-only. This is needed by the Titanium Backup tool to protect backups from being overwritten.

I can change the mount options with a remount:

```
# mount /mnt/storage/sdcard -o remount,fmode=0,dmode=0
```

The Question: How can I have the SD card mounted with the right mount options upon boot?

Answer (score 3):

Urukdroid has a special script, /system/bin/mount_sdcard.sh, that mounts the SD card upon boot. This script understands (V)FAT and EXT4. Anything else is left to the vold automounter. Archos modded vold so it could do a bit more than stock A 2.1 vold, e.g., mount EXT3 file systems.

I upgraded the file system on the SD card to EXT4, and now mount_sdcard.sh mounts the SD card upon boot with the correct mount options.

Thanks to $aur0n for helping me solve this.

Upgrading an EXT2 or EXT3 file system to EXT4 is easy, see https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#Converting_an_ext3_filesystem_to_ext4 .

Comment: Glad you manged to fix it +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: [What's the Android equivalent of /etc/fstab?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/whats-the-android-equivalent-of-etc-fstab)

From that answer:

> All startup system mounting is done with the `/etc/vold.fstab` helper
>   script.

You can go edit that script and modify the mount with the options you want, so you can have it like that on boot.

```
#######################
## Regular device mount
##
## Format: dev_mount <label> <mount_point> <part> <sysfs_path1...> 
## label        - Label for the volume
## mount_point  - Where the volume will be mounted
## part         - Partition # (1 based), or 'auto' for first usable partition.
## <sysfs_path> - List of sysfs paths to source devices
######################
```

Or you can replace dev_mount with mount.

Comment: Yes, this is known information. But /etc/vold.fstab does not have a (documented?) means to specify mount options. It may very well be impossible to obtain the correct mount at boot time (i.e., via /etc/fstab.old) but in that case I hope there's a way to automatically execute the remount command. I did put the remount in /etc/rc.local but that didn't work, apparently the SDcard has not yet been mounted when /etc/rc.local is run.

Comment: you mean dev_mount ?

Comment: did you try to replace dev_mount with your mount command ?

Comment: Do you mean that the 'dev_mount' line in /etc/vold.fstab is just a shell command, and that I can replace it by an arbitrary other command?

Comment: I guess so, I don't have an android device with me but I hope I am not wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but "I guess so" is not sufficient for a change that may brick the tablet...

Comment: @Sciurius Then see if this can help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing patience and suggestions. Unfortunately, all init scripts are run long before the process (vold?) that mounts the SD card.

Comment: @Sciurius I am sorry I couldn't do much to help.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts.