# Editing fstab to mount /data from a different partition

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, partitions, internal-sd

Is it possible to edit the fstab to mount /data, /cache etc. from a different partition on the
a.internal memory?
b.external sdcard?

Details: The default partition for /data and /cache are too small for my needs and I can manage to format the (internal) /sdcard in ext4.

Edit: My question may superficially seem to be like other questions asking for a way to increase size of /data, but it's not. Here's why:

(1) I need to do it *specifically* by editing fstab, which is the usual way of doing the same thing on a GNU/Linux desktop.
(2) The other questions don't ask about /cache and other partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. It'd have been better if you could point out what this question was missing.

Comment: Wasn't me, but the "Related" section of this question suggests you didn't check for existing solutions, and "downvote" stands for "doesn't show any research effort". Two clicks brought me to: [Mount a folder from external sd as /data](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38263/16575) – which perfectly fits your question and answers it.

Comment: @lzzy I'm aware of the link. My question is specifically about editing the 'fstab' (which is the proper 'linux way' to do this) achieve it.

Comment: For Linux, yes. But we're talking Android here: modifiying `fstab` (if it exists on your device) might require modifying the boot image. While *based on* Linux, some aspects on Android work differently. Quoting from [What's the Android equivalent of /etc/fstab?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14530/16575): *Android has no `/etc/fstab`*. Also check [these questions/answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=fstab+answers%3A1). // Moreover, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154): Better try solving your issue, not stick to your "assumed solution" ;)

Comment: @lzzy I knew the 'XY problem' would be quoted ;) (been on SE for quite long.) Your previous reply itself speaks "for" the relevance of the question, because I specifically want to know if it is possible to do this by editing fstab. As you might appreciate, people from GNU/linux land might want to know why in Dalvik/Linux the usual 'edit the fstab' doesn't work.

Comment: @lzzy my android 4.2 does have an /etc/fstab :o

Comment: *my android 4.2 does have an `/etc/fstab`* – that's why I wrote "if it exists on your device". Some devices indeed have it, but even then it often is integrated with the boot image – so changes you'd apply there would be lost on boot, which somehow defeats the purpose, right? This means you'd end up creating your own boot image – which might go beyond the scope of this site, at least "border-lining" development. If you really want to enforce this, you didn't provide sufficient details in your question: Device, Android version, ROM are missing.

Comment: @lzzy I think your previous comment should make a good first-draft version of an answer to my question. Would you care to post a polished version of the same as an answer. Coming back to the issue, I think I should read up on boot image etc. to see if/how I can proceed with my Y (just for the fun of it, as it's now clear that Y is not a viable solution to X).

Comment: You could try repartition your memory. [See this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1388996) guide on XDA forum.

Comment: Moreover there IS an android equivalent of etc/fstab. For android version 3.2 below
/system/etc/vold.fstab For android version 3.3 above
/fstab.<device>

Comment: Apart from which: `vold.fstab` IMHO usually is just for SD cards. And the other `fstab` isn't present on many devices (I've never seen it at any device I checked – and I really checked a lot, see e.g. [How can I identify partitions of an Android device from the shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27641139/2533433): if there were an `fstab` generally available, it had turned up there). Also see [What's the Android equivalent of /etc/fstab?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14530/16575) which I've linked from my answer.

Comment: Near duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56888/218526

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already expected, the way your question is phrased it looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154): There are different ways to achieve your goal (mounting `/data`, `/cache` etc. from a different partition), while your question focuses on "editing `fstab`".

For a working solution, see e.g. [Mount a folder from external sd as /data](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38263/16575): What's described there should work on all devices/ROMs – while "editing `fstab`" bears some problems:

- While that's of course the way it works on Linux, we're talking Android here – which uses a Linux kernel, but a very different setup (see: [What's the Android equivalent of /etc/fstab?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14530/16575))
- An `fstab` file is not present on many/most Android installations (see [How to list all major partitions with their labels?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/92565/16575) for details)
- If an `fstab` file is present, it's usually part of the boot image (see [initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) for details). This means, your edits to the file would be in vain: on the next boot where you'd expect them to be processed, instead the file would be overwritten from the boot image and then processed – without your changes

**Verdict:** Even if your device has an `fstab` file, you cannot simply edit it and be done. You'd have to rebuild the boot image instead – a task that goes beyond the scope of this site (which is end-user orientated, and creating/rebuilding a boot image rather is in the domain of developers). It might not be straight "off-topic", but at least border-line/gray-zone.

Comment: I don’t know how that answer can work. It creates a symlink which gets removed after boot. No ?

Comment: That comment belongs to the linked question/answer. And to shortly detail on that: It can be done via an init script that is called on boot, or via some Magisk or Xposed module. The entire thing needs root access anyway.

Comment: I am using Moto e2 android 5.0, rooted. I am facing two main problem, 1. Can’t copy /data to 2nd partition, not with uid, gid, selinux context. I am also mounting sdcard through init script. So how do I check when to create symlink, it has to be after sdcard partition gets mounted no ?