# Android O, failed to mount /system, /dev/block/dm-0 is read only

Tags: adb, 8.0-oreo

I try to mount /system in Android O to RW using the command `mount -o rw,remount /system`, and i got this feedback on terminal `dev/block/dm-0 is read-only`
*Already in adb root

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Looks like dm-verity is in effect, which by the way can only be disabled by modifying the kernel if the OS is not a debug build.

Comment: @AndyYan Hmmm, i tried `disable-verity` and it mounted successfully

Comment: You should then put it as an answer. I do doubt that your build is a debug one though, you should probably look inside `/system/build.prop`.

Comment: @JeffPang I agree with Andy. When setting up your answer, please include a short step-by-step guide – not everybody is familiar with that verity stuff :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For debug build, user have to `disable-verity` at first.

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb remount
adb shell
mount -o rw,remount /system
```

In order to know build type of your android, in `adb shell` enter the following command

```
cat /system/build.prop | grep build.type
```

Comment: after the `adb reboot` you will have to `adb root` again. Apart from that, works fine

Comment: It should be: *“only on debug build, user can `disable-verity`”*.

Comment: When I run `adb reboot`, the emulator goes offline permanently :( I can only restart it manually.

Comment: same issue as user3738870 ...

Comment: I noticed (using -shell option) that the VM is stuck in a reboot loop. ```[    4.404721] EXT4-fs (vdd1): recovery complete
[    4.407789] EXT4-fs (vdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
[    6.472377] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    6.567761] reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootloader'
[    6.572103] reboot: machine restart
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.47-01061-g22e35a1de440```

Comment: since android 10/11 it's not possible, you have to create a tmpfs: https://medium.com/@anthony.f.tannous/android-10-emulation-of-magisk-supersu-on-an-aosp-avd-de93ed080fad

Comment: `adb disable-verify` did not work for me.  I received an error: `avb_ops_user.cpp:217: ERROR: Error writing data.
avb_user_verity.c:205: ERROR: Error writing to partition 'vbmeta'
Error setting verity`